# Looping within matplotlib

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple graphs on a single set of axis.

I have a 2D array of data and want to break it down into 111 1D arrays and plot them. Here is an example of my code so far:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = linspace(1, 130, 130) # create a 1D array of 130 integers to set as the x axis
y = Te25117.data # set 2D array of data as y
plt.plot(x, y[1], x, y[2], x, y[3])
```

This code works fine, but I cannot see a way of writing a loop which will loop within the plot itself. I can only make the code work if I explicitly write a number 1 to 111 each time, which is not ideal! (The range of numbers I need to loop over is 1 to 111.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please could you give a [simple example](http://sscce.org/) of your dataset, that way we can just paste and go (rather than try and create one which satisfies your criteria) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me guess...long time matlab user?
Matplotlib automatically add a line plot to the present plot if you don't create a new one. So your code can be simply:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = linspace(1, 130, 130) # create a 1D array of 130 integers to set as the x axis
y = Te25117.data # set 2D array of data as y
L = len(y) # I assume you can infere the size of the data in this way...
#L = 111 # this is if you don't know any better
for i in range(L)
    plt.plot(x, y[i], color='mycolor',linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([1,2])
y = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

In [5]: x
Out[5]: array([1, 2])

In [6]: y
Out[6]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [7]: for y_i in y:
  ....:     plt.plot(x, y_i)
```

Will plot these in one figure.